# Math Processing Errors abound.

Tags: support

So, every single block of math is currently throwing a math processing error at me.  Is this a temporary fault with the site, a serious fault with my machine, or just failure in typing math on the part of a lot of different people?

Comment: Delete your cache and press shift+refresh.

Comment: What browser are you using? Some browsers are unsupported, I believe. (You should be able to get the exact version number using the Help menu in the browser if it is there).

Comment: The ancient post was automatically bounced to the front page. Voting to close as too localized, simply to prevent this from happening.